# javascript: I want to add html tags dynamically depending on data from firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently pull information from firebase into a generated html card. So, firebase can have 1 or 100 various recipes and my site will load all of them and display each individual recipe in a card.

Right now the cards are pretty standard. That works fine, but one section is for steps, and I don't know how to add more steps on both the add form and the displayed card.

This is what I have for the JS side of the house.

```
// MODAL   Displays Single Beer Info in the UI.*******
//****************************************
function displaySingleBeer(id, beerimage, name, type, quantity, ingredients, boilTime, mashTemp, mashOutTemp, steps, targetOG, targetFG){
    var div = document.getElementById(id) ||
        createAndInsertBeerCard(id, beerimage, name, type, quantity, ingredients, boilTime, mashTemp, mashOutTemp, steps, targetOG, targetFG);
    div.querySelector('.beerimage').src = beerimage;
    div.querySelector('.name').textContent = name;
    div.querySelector('.type').textContent = type;
    div.querySelector('.quantity').textContent = quantity;
    div.querySelector('.ingredients').textContent = ingredients;
    div.querySelector('.boilTime').textContent = boilTime;
    div.querySelector('.mashTemp').textContent = mashTemp;
    div.querySelector('.mashOutTemp').textContent = mashOutTemp;
    div.querySelector('.steps').textContent = steps;
    div.querySelector('.targetOG').textContent = targetOG;
    div.querySelector('.targetFG').textContent = targetFG;
}

// MODAL
function createAndInsertBeerCard(id) {

  var container = document.createElement('div');
  console.log('expected id in createAndInsertBeerCard', id);
  container.innerHTML = MODAL_TEMPLATE(id);
  const div = container.firstChild;

  //This sets the id equal to the firebase document ID
  div.setAttribute('id', id);

  //figure out where to insert new message
  const existingMessages1 = beerCardElement.children;
  
  if (existingMessages1.length === 0) {
      beerCardElement.appendChild(div);
  } else {
      let messageListNode1 = existingMessages1[0];
      beerCardElement.insertBefore(div, messageListNode1);
  }
  return;
}
```

///////////////   EDIT

I figured out part of my ask.   I created an array and I'm able to add individual steps to firebase.

```
var addFormSteps = [];

 function addStep() {
 var list = document.createElement("li");
 list.className = "align-items-center";
  list.innerHTML = addBeerForm.steps.value;
  container.appendChild(list);

  addFormSteps.push(addBeerForm.steps.value);
  console.log(addFormSteps);
  addBeerForm.steps.value = '';  
  return addFormSteps;
 }
```

///

From there, I'd like to query firebase and display the steps in my page.  For instance, if I have 3 steps in one recipe, I only want 3 displayed. 5 for 5 and so on.

I'm working on this ..

```
      query.steps.forEach(step => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.value = step;
        formSteps.appendChild(li);
      })
```

///
and putting it inside my previous function that displays the results.

Comment: Welcome to SO andrew73a, I have a few questions regarding your question: what do you mean with "Add more steps"? Your code looks fine, do you get any error message? Can you give more details on what you want to achieve and what you have tried already? Also, I assume that the Firestore part of your code is working as expected, correct? If not, please share it as well.

Comment: @ralemos added edits

Comment: From what I understood you need to query the data from firestore, correct? If so, take a look at the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) for getting data, in there you will find an example that you can apply to your code to fetch data from firestore.

Comment: I have the query taken care of.  But the HTML is fairly static.  For instance, if a user submits a recipe without ingredients, the card that's displayed will still have the <p> tag associated with the ingredients. And I'd like to exclude that <p> tag all together if the value is empty on firestore.